# Valores en Recyclerview se cambian al hacer scroll hacia abajo y regresar

Tags: android

```
    public class RecyclerViewAdapter_Accueil extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter_Accueil.RestaurantViewHolder> {
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private List<Restaurant> restaurantList;

    private int descuento;



    public RecyclerViewAdapter_Accueil( List<Restaurant> restaurant, Double latitude, Double longitude) {
        this.restaurantList=restaurant;
        this.latitude=latitude;
        this.longitude=longitude;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter_Accueil.RestaurantViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_restaurants, parent, false);
        RestaurantViewHolder viewHolder = new RestaurantViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RestaurantViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Restaurant mItems=this.restaurantList.get(position);

        String nombreRestaurant=mItems.getName();
        holder.tvTituloRestaurant.setText(nombreRestaurant);

        descuento=mItems.tomarPromocion();

        if (descuento>0){
            holder.tvRestaurantPromocion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tvRestaurantPromocion.setText(descuento+"%");
        }
        holder.test10(mItems);

       // holder.test(restaurantList);
        holder.test2(restaurantList);
        holder.test3(restaurantList,latitude,longitude);





    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (restaurantList == null) ? 0 : restaurantList.size();
    }



    public static class RestaurantViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

//        public ImageView imageView;
        CustomFontTextView tvTituloRestaurant;
        CustomFontTextView tvStateReservation;
        CustomFontTextView tvKm;
        CustomFontTextView tvRestaurantPromocion;

        CustomFontTextView [] tvTag =new CustomFontTextView[6];

        ImageView ivRestaurantList;

        public RestaurantViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
//            imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivRestaurant);

            tvKm= (CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvKm);
            tvTituloRestaurant = (CustomFontTextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTituloRestaurant);
            tvStateReservation = (CustomFontTextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStateReservation);
            ivRestaurantList = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivRestaurantList);
            tvRestaurantPromocion = (CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRestaurantPromocion);

            tvTag[0] = (CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTag1);
            tvTag[1] = (CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTag2);
            tvTag[2] = (CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTag3);
            tvTag[3] = (CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTag4);
            tvTag[4] = (CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTag5);
            tvTag[5] = (CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTag6);


        }

        public void test10(Restaurant restaurant){
            if(restaurant.getTags()!=null) {
                for (int x = 0; x < restaurant.getTags().size(); x++) {
                    String tag = restaurant.getTags().get(x);
                    tvTag[x].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tvTag[x].setText(tag);
                }
            }
        }



        public void test3(List<Restaurant> restaurantList,Double latitude,Double longitude){


            Location locationMain = new Location("");
            locationMain.setLatitude(latitude);
            locationMain.setLongitude(longitude);

            Location locationRestaurant = new Location("");
            locationRestaurant.setLatitude(restaurantList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getLatitude());
            locationRestaurant.setLongitude(restaurantList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getLongitude());

            float distanceInMeters = locationMain.distanceTo(locationRestaurant);
            double distanceInKm= distanceInMeters/1000;

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            tvKm.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(distanceInKm))+" Km");
        }

        public void test2(List<Restaurant> restaurantList){

            switch (restaurantList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getStateOrder()){
                case 0:
                    tvStateReservation.setText("Sur place/ À emporter");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tvStateReservation.setText("Sur place");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tvStateReservation.setText("À emporter");
                    break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

El problema esta en el metodo llamado test10 
Donde reviso el tamaño de la lista tags proveniente del objeto en la lista de objetos,  para hacer aparecer textviews y mostrar los tags correspondientes

Funciona, pero cuando recorro toda la lista, voy haciendo scroll hacia abajo, al regresar, aparecen tags que no deberian ir en la que ya se mostraba bien, aparecen los tags correctos y 1 tag que no deberia ir.

Por ejemplo en el restaurante estaban los tags Italiana y Pizza ,
al subir aparece italiana, pizza y tradicional

Alado estaba un restaurant Japones , antes decia japones, ahora dice, japones y pizza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo idea de porque, pero parece que al regresar los TextViews que cambie su visibilidad a Visible, quedaban asi para los siguientes, asi que agregue esto :

```
public void test10(Restaurant restaurant){
        if(restaurant.getTags()!=null) {
            for (int x = 0; x < restaurant.getTags().size(); x++) {
                String tag = restaurant.getTags().get(x);
                tvTag[x].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvTag[x].setText(tag);
      --->Esto          for(int y = restaurant.getTags().size();y<6;y++){
                    tvTag[y].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Y se arreglo por el momento.